# Visual Studio 2015 Error Windows Phone Application

Tags: c#, mobile, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, mobile-application

I have a little problem. I installed Visual Studio 2015.

I click on `New Project -> Templates -> VisualC # -> Windows -> Windows Phone`

and all kinds of application: csApplication, PanoramaApplication, Pivot, cs

give the same error message

```
Error: the model has attempted to load the assembly of the component

'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.Base, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

For more information about this issue and how to activate the model, see the documentation about customizing templates
```

How can I fix this? I have already visited the page for the models but I do not understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some issues in installation, you can try to uninstall and reinstall "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015" to solve this issue.

1. Open Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates;
2. uninstall "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015";
3. restart Visual Studio 2015;
4. Open Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates aging;
5. install "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015";
6. restart Visual Studio 2015